# Issue with McAfee End-Point-Encryption reading the disk constantly

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption

Recently installed McAfee End-Point-Encryption in my new laptop. After installing the HDD is on constant read state only, causing high heat emission. Is it a known issue? If it is, is there any solution?

Comment: Presumably, it's still doing the initial background encryption. Once it's finished everything should settle down.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you very much for the pointer. When i checked the status of EPE, there it showed encrypting files in progress with estimated time. It could have shown a pop explaining this. Thank you very much.

Comment: welcome. I suppose I could make this an answer & beg the points from you if you click the 'tick' ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, it's still doing the initial background encryption. Once it's finished everything should settle down.

As mentioned in comments, there is a status display, though you need to go find it; it doesn't pop up to inform you of the current progress.